# Apply wrapper with custom style to tinyMCE element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tinymce-4

I have a jquery script that will detect any changed in any form input elements on my page, and apply a custom CSS style to them to show the user which fields he has edited.
For tinyMCE I had to change the code slightly, using the setup: intialisation parameter, it seems to work more or less, but it also seems to break my tinyMCE editor.

I'm using this initialisation code:

```
<script>
tinymce.init({
selector: "textarea",
plugins: [
    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
    "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
    "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
],
toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
,setup : function(ed){
    //save original value to check later if content is changed or not
    ed.on('init',function(){
        this.OrigVal = this.getContent();
    });
    //on change compare content against orignal value
    ed.on('change', function(){
        if(this.getContent() !== this.OrigVal)
        {
            //Content changed, add 'Edited' wrapper style
            if($(this.getContainer()).parent().hasClass('ChangedInput') === false)
            {
                $(this.getContainer()).wrap("<span class='ChangedInput'></span>");
                $(this.getContainer()).addClass('ChangedInput');
            }
            FormUnsaved++;
        }
        else
        {
            //the current value is the same as the original, remove the class from this element and deduct one from the FormUnsaved counter
            $(this).parent().removeClass('ChangedInput');
            $(this).removeClass('ChangedInput');
            FormUnsaved--;
        }
    });
}
 });
 </script>
```

The custom style I'm applying wraps the tinyMCE editor in a span element, and then applies the 'ChangedInput' style to this span. This puts a green border around and a nice icon behind the element. This works with the tinyMCE editor (green border and icon appear after editing), but the content in the editor is gone and can't be edited again. A page reload is required before the editor is working again.

See here for an example:
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Nceaab

Am I approaching this wrong, or is this impossible with tinyMCE?
Note that I want to apply this code to a lot of existing forms so I'm looking for a solution that I can apply centrally in my header file.

Comment: maybe you could just check on returns value of aria-disabled attributes of undo and redo buttons , that tells it's been edited true or false it's built-in. and if it does , add a class to the wrapper `<div aria-disabled="false" aria-label="Undo" role="button" id="mce_24" ` . You may as well look for this function in tinymce and tune it

Comment: @GCyrillus: Maybe you misunderstood my question, it's not the detecting of changed content that is causing me trouble, but the wrapping and applying of the custom style. As you can see in the example the change is detected correctly, but as soon as the span wrapper is applied the content of tinyMCE vanishes and the field becomes uneditable/broken

Comment: i understood, and my point is you should use another method , since , it kills tinymce and since tinymce already checks if content is modified. you already got the wheel , use it :)

Comment: It's not the method of detecting that's breaking tinyMCE, it's the applying of the style. If I were to put a simple 'console.log(' test');' instead of applying the style and wrapping, it would work fine

Comment: that's what i say somehow , your method breaks it, use another and just apply a box-shadow:0 0 0 1px green to #mce_39 . Beside , you do not wrap a div with a span ?

Comment: OK And how would you apply this style? Could you give an example by forking my fiddle?